Jest encountered an unexpected token '<' when running tests with TypeScript and React
Description:
I'm trying to run Jest test cases in my TypeScript and React project, but I'm encountering the following error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
This error occurs when Jest tries to parse a file containing JSX syntax. Below are the relevant parts of my project configuration:
Project Configuration:
package.json
{
  "name": "ignite-mentorship",
  "version": "1.0.20",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "dev": "next dev --experimental-https --experimental-https-key local.blueprint.com.key --experimental-https-cert local.blueprint.com.crt",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest --config ./jest.config.js"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": ["prettier --write", "eslint --fix", "git add"],
    "*.{md,mdx,css,json}": ["prettier --write"]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.10.8",
    "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support": "^0.11.2",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.25.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.3",
    "next": "^14.2.13",
    "next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.19",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.53.0",
    "react-select": "^5.8.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.7",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.25.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.25.7",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.25.7",
    "@changesets/changelog-github": "^0.4.8",
    "@changesets/cli": "^2.27.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^16.0.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.13",
    "@types/node": "18.11.19",
    "@types/react": "18.0.27",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.34",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.50.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.50.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "eslint": "8.33.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.6",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "husky": "8.0.3",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "lint-staged": "13.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.2.5",
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  }
}

jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  roots: ["<rootDir>"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    // Update to include .tsx files
  },
  // Ensure this pattern matches your test files moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'json', 'node'],
  testRegex: "(/_tests_/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
  // Include .tsx
  collectCoverage: true,
  clearMocks: true,
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
};

babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    ["@babel/preset-react", { runtime: "automatic" }],
  ],
};

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "types": ["node", "jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom"],
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["./components/*"],
      "@/lib/*": ["./lib/*"],
      "@/hooks/*": ["./hooks/*"],
      "@/types/*": ["./types/*"],
      "@/shared/*": ["./shared/*"],
      "@/auth": ["./auth"],
      "@/public/*": ["./public/*"]
    },
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [{ "name": "next" }]
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "src",
    "_tests_"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "cypress"]
}

jest.setup.js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

Error Details:
When I run npx jest --verbose, I see the following error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
Steps Taken:

Ensured Babel and Jest configurations are correct.

Checked file extensions.

Cleared Jest cache.

Ran Jest with detailed debugging.


Request:
How can I resolve this error and ensure that Jest properly transforms JSX syntax in my TypeScript and React project?

Bases on https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/options/babelConfig/ you also need to specify babelConfig: true, to have it pick up your babel config. Also please make an effort to properly format your code, it's near impossible to read

Hi @apokryfos, thanks for responding, bro this was my first question to stackoverflow, but I have formatted my code now, can you check now please? This didn't work for me.
